# mongodb node.js findOneAndUpdate doesn't return upserted value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am currently using mongodb node.js driver of version 3.6 (not using mongoose), and looking for how to return the newly created value once `fineOneAndUpdate()` finished.

In [the document](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate), it says, to return the document that has been created when there's no result exists, I need to pass `returnDocument: "after"` and `upsert: true` as options. However, it doesn't work at all and returns `value: null` **even though a new document has been already created**.

What I am trying to do below is to upsert a user document when `auth.type` and `auth.sub` don't exist, and return the newly created document.

Is there's an error in my query or is it a matter of the version I'm using? Thanks in advance.

```
const upsertUser = async (user) => {
  try {
    const updated = await mongoClient
      .db("test")
      .collection("user")
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        { "auth.type": user.oauthType, "auth.sub": user.sub },
        {
          $set: {
            email: user.email,
            "auth.type": user.oauthType,
            "auth.sub": user.sub ? user.sub : null,
          },
        },
        { returnDocument: "after", upsert: true },
      );
    return {
      _id: updated.value._id.toString(),
      email: updated.value.email,
      oauth: updated.value.auth.type,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the package dependency compatibility using `npm outdated`, and found out one package called `connect-mongodb-session` requires version 3.6.12 so it stays not updated. Since I wasn't using it anymore, I deleted the package and updated the mongodb driver from 3.6.12 to 3.7.3(wanted), and all works like a charm.